# Drupal integration with active directory using windows authentication method

Tags: drupal, active-directory

We are trying to integrate Drupal 9 and Active directory 2019 using SAML auth 2.0 and we are using SAMLAuth drupal module.
But the Active directory we are integrating with, is configured with windows authentication method (auto login) for other applications and we can't change this.

The active directory is currently showing unsupported authentication method error after trying accessing the SSO url.

So how can we make it work?